# creating sef links and changing plus sign (+) with dash (-)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I've searched the web and I tried to solve problem but I could not figure out how.
I'd like to redirect dizisozluk.net/words to dizisozluk.net/ne-demek/anlami/words and change plus (+) sign to dash (-) sign. For example

- dizisozluk.net/family+tree

to

- dizisozluk.net/ne-demek/anlami/family-tree

My old code is here

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?word=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?word=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I change this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `words` just a fixed keyword or you want to redirect everything to `/anlami/`

Comment: Also what happens to existing `search.php` rules? Will `search.php` be moved into `anlami/` directory now?

Comment: `words` is not a fixed keyword. It's a variable.
Originally, I want to change https://www.dizisozluk.net/search.php?word=keywords to https://www.dizisozluk.net/ne-demek/anlami/keywords

Comment: search.php stays the same. Actually, there is no directory such as anlami/ or ne-demek/

anlami and ne demek means (meaning) in Turkish, since my website is a English to Turkish dictionary, I want to use those words (ne demek, anlami) in SEF links for SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+ne-demek/anlami/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ne-demek/anlami/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?word=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ne-demek/anlami/%1? [R=301,L]

# recursive rule to replace space by - from URI OR query string (anywhere)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ne-demek/anlami/(.+)$ search.php?word=$1 [QSA,L]
```